# Не могу подключить свой js файл к vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind

К index.html моего vue проекта подключил свой джаваскрипт и выводится ошибка
**Unexpected token '<'** - смотрю свой файл а оказыватся **он превратил его в некий html** а мой код просто добавил в тег script.
Как это обойти чтоб он не трогал мой js и просто к нему подключился (Этот файл cdn tailwind css если чё)
А ещё стоить отметить что меня **vue 2**

Comment: Приложи содержимое файла куда подключаешь js

Comment: `cdn` подключают в `html` через тег `script`но лучше использовать `npm` и `import`